# How to add if statement

Tags: php, wordpress

Need some help with trying to add on an if statement to the following code.

```
// determine email
$email = '<a href="mailto:' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'resource_email', true) . '">'. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'resource_email', true) .'</a>';
$tpl = str_replace( '%%EMAIL%%', $email, $tpl );
```

What I would like to do, is this:

If there's an email display it like this...

```
<p><i class="icon"></i><a href="mailto:' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'resource_email', true) . '">'. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'resource_email', true) .'</a><p>
```

If there's not email, display nothing.

Not sure how to do this, I've tried this, but failed :-)

```
// determine email
$email = '<a href="mailto:' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'resource_email', true) . '">'. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'resource_email', true) .'</a>';
if ($email) {
    '<i class="ss-mail"></i><h6>Email</h6><p>';
    $tpl = str_replace( '%%EMAIL%%', $email, $tpl );
    '</p>';
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You gotta use `echo` to print strings

Comment: what is the output of `echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'resource_email', true)` ?

Comment: your sample if() statement will ALWAYS succeed, because you're setting `$email` to be something non-false immediately beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just wrap it in an if statement since get_post_meta() won't return a result if there isn't an email address. So:

```
if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'resource_email',true)){
.../your existing code ...
}
```

Comment: To be more technically accurate, it returns an empty string when you're returning a single post_meta value. The empty string evaluates to false in an if() statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$resource_email = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'resource_email', true);
if( !empty( $resource_email ) ) {
    $email = '<a href="mailto:' . $resource_email . '">'. $resource_email .'</a>';
    $tpl = str_replace( '%%EMAIL%%', $email, $tpl );
    echo '<i class="ss-mail"></i><h6>Email</h6><p>';
    echo $tpl;
    echo '</p>';
} else {
    $email = ' ';
    $tpl = str_replace( '%%EMAIL%%', $email, $tpl );
    echo $tpl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I do this and there's not email, I still see `%%EMAIL%%`

Comment: Doesn't seem to be what I needed here. Thanks though